# how can i display the start date, the end date and the duration from the lightbox in dhtmlx gantt?

Tags: javascript, dhtmlx

in my web application J2EE i'm using dhtmlx to display gantt chart, 
i displayed the value of description from the lightbox

```
alert(gantt.getLightboxSection("description").getValue())
```

i don't know how to display the other fields, i used

```
alert(gantt.getLightboxSection("time").getValue());
```

but i had [object object]. 
how can i display the start_date, end_date and the duration from the lightbox ?
here the picture of the lightbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time control is mapped to several properties, so it returns an object with following structure

```
{
  start_date: Date,
  end_date: Date,
  duration: Number
}
```

If you want to view it in the alert you need to stringify the object to JSON:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(gantt.getLightboxSection("time").getValue()));
```

Sample http://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/snippet/ed9eab5c

If you need a formatted output, you can access the object values - http://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/snippet/ff33992d

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i want to draw directly in the chart gantt,the problem is  if  I add a new task with 4 days as duration it appears just one cell not four.

Comment: check the Paul's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29438891/how-can-i-save-tasks-in-dhtmlx-gantt#answer-29468758) , seems like you simply do not apply the lightbox values to the client-side gantt