# How can i save tasks in dhtmlx gantt?

Tags: javascript, dhtmlx

I used dhtmlx for chart gantt, I succeed in saving  tasks in the data base, the problem is that when I add a new task there is no change in the chart,
for example if I add a new task with 4 days  as duration it appears just one cell not four ones and also for the other properties.

Here the code of adding a new task :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    gantt.init("gantt_here");   
    gantt.attachEvent("onLightboxSave", function(id, task, is_new){
    mnth = ("0" + (task.start_date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2),
    day  = ("0" + task.start_date.getDate()).slice(-2);
    mnth = ("0" + (task.end_date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2),
    day  = ("0" + task.end_date.getDate()).slice(-2);

   $.post("Control",{id:task.id,duration:task.duration,text:task.text,start_date:[ day,mnth,  task.start_date.getFullYear() ].join("-").toString()},function(data){

  alert(data);

  }) ;

 gantt.hideLightbox();
   });

</script>
```

Comment: If you save and load a correct start_date and duration, it should be displayed in the chart.

Please show the values that are sent to the server and the sample of JSON data that displays the wrong duration.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning '**true**' from onLightboxSave handler http://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_onlightboxsave_event.html

If you return '**false**' or '**undefined**' (as in your case), the form stays opened and the form values are not applied to the client-side.

Returning 'true' will save values and close the form, so you won't need to call hideLightbox manually

```
gantt.attachEvent("onLightboxSave", function(id, task, is_new){
   var dateToStr = gantt.date.date_to_str("%d-%m-%Y");

   $.post("Control",{
      id:task.id,
      duration:task.duration,
      text:task.text,
      start_date:dateToStr(task.start_date)
   },function(data){
      alert(data);
   }) ;

   return true;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not work, the lightbox stays opened and there is no task saved in the database.

Comment: Please provide more details or show some kind of a demo. Returning true from the handler confirms saving of the lightbox and closes it, as it happens in this demo
http://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/snippet/6ffde6d2
if it works differently in your case - probably there is some js error during the process, check the browser console.